# check validity of following manipulation

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

in my algebra  book,there is written  following well known  identity

$e^{2*\pi*i}=1$

generally we can  use also  this  identity  $e^{k*\pi*i}=(-1)^k$

and  if instead of $k$,we put  $2$ we get $(-1)^2=1$

but know  book asks
what is wrong with  following  thing: $e^{2*a*\pi*i}=e^{(2*\pi*i)*a}=1^a=1$?

i have tried to figure out if what kind of  $a$  gives me  wrong result,i was thinking that  $a=1/2$,as  it would be  $\sqrt{1}=1$  and  $\sqrt{1}=-1$  and second case makes this wrong,but i am not sure if this is correct way.if $a=0$  then everything is ok,but if $a<0$ then it makes i think  wrong,because $1^k$  for all  $k$ is  $1$,but on the other hand because

$e^{k*\pi*i}=(-1)^k$
and  $k=2*a$   it maybe  square root  from negative number,which is complex number and  not equal to $1$,am i wrong?please help me

Comment: i think you're on the right track...  $1^a=1$ is true for real numbers, but if $a$ is not an integer, then $e^{2a\pi i}$ is complex...

Comment: or to make sure,if  $a$ in this case is negative right?if it is directly complex  clear,but if it is  integer  but negative then  also fail equality right?